# Assignment in cuda 11.6 running extremely slow

Tags: c++, cuda

I am testing a customised Z buffer kernel in cuda.
In a short conlusion: to check if `X` number of points is inside `Y` number of polygons, and return the front polygon ID for each points. The parallel part is to compute each point with all polygons.

The whole thing worked with no error and it did transfer data to the device and return correct result to the host.

However I found a huge time consumption in the last line `values[i] = val;`

The question is actually stupid. I believe I did the wrong way to assign values in the kernel. Could you suggest the correct way to do this assignment?

Many thanks!

For a better understanding of the data structure in the kernel:

- `float* position_dist` stores:

1. first comes all test point x,y,z in a sequence of `point0, point1, ... ,point(X-1)`
2. then all polygon points x,y,z and z buffer distance in a sequence of
   `poly0.p0, dist0, poly0.p1, dist0, poly0.p2, dist0, poly0.p3, dist0, ... , poly(Y-1).p0, dist(Y-1), poly(Y-1).p1, dist(Y-1), poly(Y-1).p2, dist(Y-1), poly(Y-1).p3, dist(Y-1)`. Thus each polygon has 16 values when offset.

- `int* values` stores:
  default value of -1. It will update to `polyID`and return to the host.

```
CUDA_GLOBAL void computeOcclusion_kernel(float* position_dist, int* values, int numPt, int numPositions)
{
    uint i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < numPt && i % 3 == 0)
    {
        Point pt(position_dist[i + 0], position_dist[i + 1], position_dist[i + 2]);

        uint offset = numPt - i;

        float dist = 10000000;
        int val = -1;
        for (int o = i; o < i + numPositions; o += 16)
        {
            int j = o + offset;
            int polyID = (j - numPt) / 16;

            Point p0(position_dist[j + 0], position_dist[j + 1], position_dist[j + 2]);
            Point p1(position_dist[j + 4], position_dist[j + 5], position_dist[j + 6]);
            Point p2(position_dist[j + 8], position_dist[j + 9], position_dist[j + 10]);
            Point p3(position_dist[j + 12], position_dist[j + 13], position_dist[j + 14]);

            if (position_dist[j + 3] < dist)
            {
                if(inPoly(pt,p0,p1,p2,p3))
                {
                    val = polyID;
                    dist = position_dist[j + 3];
                }
            }
        }
        values[i] = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: "However I found a huge time consumption in the last line `values[i] = val;`"  My guess is you commented out that line and saw a huge speedup.  That kind of approach and observation is misleading, because when you did that, all of the other code in your kernel disappeared also because you are dealing with an optimizing compiler.    If that is what you did, then your conclusion of a huge time consumption on that line is incorrect.

Comment: Hey thanks Robert. Yes I commented out that line but also did different ways to avoid compiler optimization. 
e.g 
values[i] = 0;
int x = val;
these two ways also speed it up a lot. Not sure what's the issue..

Comment: Those two lines: { uint i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; if (i < numPt && i % 3 == 0)} are not optimal! You throw away every 2 of 3 threads from the beginning. Better multiply the thread number with 3 to get only numbers divisible by 3. In addition, your memory accesses should as best as is possible be to successive memory locations within a warp of 32 threads. Otherwise preload the data to shared memory and then take it from there. Your threads within a warp would switch from generally loading/copying data to working on specific data. Uncoalesced memory accesses could be 32x slower.

Comment: Hey Sebastian, thanks!
I am very new to cuda. Could you throw an example of optimizing the threads as successive memory locations?

Comment: First there is the concept of a warp (groups of 32 consecutive threads). When you access global memory, it is fastest, if those 32 threads read or write 128 bytes of aligned memory. If this is not possible, it should be at least groups of 32 bytes. Then there is shared memory. It is arranged into 32 banks of 4 bytes. After 128 bytes bank 0 starts again. Access is fastest, if each thread accesses a different bank, but the memory locations do not have to be consecutive. This is used with creative indexing. E.g. a float[32][33] array can be accessed column-wise and row-wise without bank conflict.

Comment: You should arrange your memory storage accordingly. As mentioned, do not skip 2 of 3 threads in your if instruction. The GPU can only end whole warps. If you skip them, they need complete resources (including for calculation). That is also true, if your program flow diverges, the deactivated threads of a warp in an if/else need resources, as if they are running both the if and else block. Instead of one position_dist with x y and z store three different one, one array each for x, y and z. Then as you access with [i], it results in consecutive memory addresses, as is best for global memory.

Comment: Here each single access counts, you cannot say, even if there are multiple in one C/C++ instruction line. You should do the same for the other points you want to load. Rearrange them that the lowest array dimension is the one used for a warp (typically as a threadIdx.x of size 32). You can define a position_dist[numPositions][numPt] and round up numPt to a multiple of 128. So basically exchange the two array dimensions. as numPositions you also use the maximum value over all points.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!
Do you think that is the only issue caused slow performance in the kernel?
I am asking because I also tested assigning other values to my value[i] or assigning polyID to a new int. {e.g values[i] = 0; int x = val;}. It was running 100x faster than {value[i] = faceID}. I understand the waste of threads but it should not make such a huge difference if thats the only issue

Comment: Here Robert's answer applies: With such a simple assignment (0) the optimizer optimizes away all other memory accesses and some computations normally needed to get to val. You can prove it by letting the kernel run in a longer loop over many points and just adding up val values locally and saving them only once in the end of the kernel instead of saving in each iteration. Both should take similarly long, as it probably is not the one memory write, but lots of memory reads. Also download Nvidia Compute Nsight.

Comment: Huge thanks Sebastian and Robert! It speedup 3x by simply changing the first line to {if (i < numBuffer/3){i *= 3;} instead of {if (i < numBuffer && i % 3 == 0)}. Will continue to optimize it further from your comments. Thanks again!

Comment: How many numPositions do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks agian for the comments!
I restructured the kernel by using successive memory locations and dynamic shared memories.

It is working correctly now.

```
CUDA_GLOBAL void computeOcclusion_kernel(float* position_dist, int* values, int numPt, int numPositions)
{
    extern __shared__ int shared[];

    for (uint i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        i < numPt/ 3;
        i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
    {
        uint t = i * 3;
        Point pt(position_dist[t + 0], position_dist[t + 1], position_dist[t + 2]);

        uint offset = numPt - t;

        float dist = 10000000;
        shared[i] = -1;

        for (int o = i; o < t + numPositions; o += 16)
        {
            int j = o + offset;
            int polyID = (j - numPt) / 16;

            Point p0(position_dist[j + 0], position_dist[j + 1], position_dist[j + 2]);
            Point p1(position_dist[j + 4], position_dist[j + 5], position_dist[j + 6]);
            Point p2(position_dist[j + 8], position_dist[j + 9], position_dist[j + 10]);
            Point p3(position_dist[j + 12], position_dist[j + 13], position_dist[j + 14]);

            if (position_dist[j + 3] < dist)
            {
                if(inPoly(pt,p0,p1,p2,p3))
                {
                    shared[i] = polyID;
                    dist = position_dist[j + 3];
                }
            }
        }
        __syncthreads();
        buffervalues[i] = shared[i];
    }
}
```

It is also needed to declare dynamic shared memory size in the kernel launch.

```
computeOcclusion_kernel <<< grid, block, NUM_BUFFER/3*sizeof(int) >>>...
```

However, dynamic shared memory size can only be maximum 48kb thats what I understood - in this case my buffer size only works under 48KB/sizeof(int) = 1200.

It is way more less than what I required. I need something like: buffer_X * buffer_Y * 4 = 4MB.

I will look at an alternative strategy to do so.

Comment: You can get slightly more dynamic memory with `cudaFuncSetAttribute(kernelname, cudaFuncAttributeMaxDynamicSharedMemorySize, 65536);` (example with Turing, which allows a maximum of 64 KB). This has to be activated once, before calling the kernel. Maximum depends on compute capability version of the GPU.

Comment: Your global memory accesses are not optimal yet: E.g. `position_dist[t + 0]` for initializing `pt` uses `t=i*3`, so each thread accesses memory with a distance of `3*4=12 Bytes` instead of `4 Bytes`. You either need 3 separate arrays for x, y and z, or an array, which you access as `position_dist[0 * 2048 + i]` for x and `position_dist[1 * 2048 + i]` for y and `position_dist[2 * 2048 + i]` for z, where 2048 is chosen to be large enough to hold all `numPt` and is divisible by 32 elements (alignment of 32 * 4 Bytes = 128 Bytes). It can be calculated on the fly, given as parameter or hard-coded.

Comment: Best solution is, if you can provide this point data in the optimal data arrangement. If you have no easy influence over this memory layout and the data changes too fast or this is too much data to copy/convert and save to global memory, you have to copy a small block of this existing layout to shared memory cooperatively between the threads. This would be a separate loop, which you would only optimize for global memory access.

Comment: You currently use the shared memory only as shared[i]. So you access only one variable (within an outer loop iteration), which you have written yourself. You could have just used one local variable instead and written it at the end like in your first version. Also __syncthreads() is only needed for synchronizing shared memory between different warps within a block. To sync execution and/or shared memory within a warp there is __syncwarp().

Comment: But it could make sense to cache all polygon points in shared memory. If your shared memory is too small for it, go for the maximum, and run everything in a loop, where you reload new polygon data, test all the points, synchronize, load next polygon data into shared memory, test all the points, etc. - With this way, you have to load each polygon data only once. (Or at least once per multiprocessor/block.)

Comment: Should the inner for loop be ` for (int o = i; o < t + numPositions; o += 16)` or `int o = t`?